# Boot strap button group change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im starting to learn JavaScript/jQuery and have the code below that works but there must be some shorter code to write for this simple function.

**The function:**
Font awesome icon to show and change when i choose access level in the boot strap button group.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#access").html(' Alla');
  $("#accessIcon").addClass('fa-globe');

  $('#access_input').val(0);

});
/*
' access
' 0 = all
' 1 = friends
' 2 = private
*/


$(".access").click(function(e) {


  var accessId = $(this).attr('id');

  if (accessId == 0) {
    //alert("Alla = "+ accessId);
    $("#access").html(' Alla');

    $("#accessIcon").removeClass('fa-group');
    $("#accessIcon").removeClass('fa-eye');

    $("#accessIcon").addClass('fa-globe');

    $('#access_input').val(accessId);

  } else if (accessId == 1) {
    //alert("Vänner = "+ accessId);
    $("#access").html(' Vänner');
    $("#accessIcon").removeClass('fa-globe');
    $("#accessIcon").removeClass('fa-eye');

    $("#accessIcon").addClass('fa-group');

    $('#access_input').val(accessId);

  } else if (accessId == 2) {
    //alert("Privat = "+ accessId);
    $("#access").html('Privat');
    $("#accessIcon").removeClass('fa-globe');
    $("#accessIcon").removeClass('fa-group');

    $("#accessIcon").addClass('fa-eye');

    $('#access_input').val(accessId);
  } else {
    alert("inget alternativ valt! = " + accessId);
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<!-- Start inputs -->

<input type="text" id="access_input" value="">
<br>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i id="accessIcon" class="fa ">&nbsp;</i>  <span id="access">Action</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="access" id="0"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Alla</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="access" id="1"><i class="fa fa-group"></i> Vänner</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="access" id="2"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> Privat</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I advice you to start with angularjs and the angularjs bootstrap module https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to each links with class 'access' data attributes first for icon class name and second for title. Example for first link:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="access" id="0" data-icon="globe" data-title="Alla">
```

And your onclick can be simplified to:

```
$(".access").click(function(e) {
  $("#access").html($(this).data('title'));
  $("#accessIcon").removeClass();
  $("#accessIcon").addClass('fa fa-' + $(this).data('icon'));
  $('#access_input').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: +1 I actually prefer this to my own answer. The icon and the title are both of UI concern only, so having them tightly coupled with the markup is fine.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I completely agree with you

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters, I would extract the UI details that are buried deep in your conditions, so that you may use variables instead:

```
var accessTypes = [
  { title: 'Alla', icon: 'fa-globe' },
  { title: 'Vänner', icon: 'fa-group' },
  { title: 'Privat', icon: 'fa-eye' }
];
```

Then you could simply do:

```
$(".access").click(function(e) {
  var accessId = $(this).attr('id');
  var access = accessTypes[accessId];

  $("#access").html(' ' + access.title);
  $("#accessIcon").attr('class', 'fa ' + access.icon);
  $('#access_input').val(accessId);
});
```

Note that this works only because the `id` of your buttons are matching the array index in `accessTypes`. This solution will break down once you add a second set of buttons for something else.

I would suggest that you move away from relying on `id` to a data attribute for this purpose, and I would also use string identifiers, although doing just either one of them would be sufficient to solve the problem.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="access" data-id="all"> <!-- etc -->
```

You would then use:

```
var accessTypes = {
  all: { title: 'Alla', icon: 'fa-globe' },
  friends: { title: 'Vänner', icon: 'fa-group' },
  'private': { title: 'Privat', icon: 'fa-eye' }
};
```

And...

```
$(".access").click(function(e) {
  var accessId = $(this).data('id');
  var access = accessTypes[accessId];

  ...
});
```